# having trouble importing CSV

Tags: python, csv, import

I usually use AWS s3 to import csv files and it is really easy. Trying to import this csv file straight from the file explorer and continuing to get an error. Is it different?

```
import pd as pandas

month = pd.read_csv("12Month.csv")
print(month)

Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '12Month.csv'
```

Comment: Your import is wrong, this should be ' import pandas as pd ', and if your file is not being found you should provide the full path for it, then it should work.

Comment: import pandas as pd

    month = pd.read_csv(r'Z:\Company\Projects\Mason & 
    Jeriel\Usage\12Month.csv')
    df_month = pd.DataFrame(month)                    
    print(df_month)

this is my new code and is still getting the same error

Comment: try `with open("12Month.csv", 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        print(line) ` 
to see if python can access your file. If not, maybe there is a hidden extension, being the "original" name as "12Month.csv.csv"

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to state the full path.

```
import pandas as pd
month = pd.read_csv(r"C: etc... 12Month.csv"")
```

or use :

```
 from pathlib import Path 
 wdir = Path.cwd()
 filename = path(wdir,"12Month.csv")
 month = pd.read_csv(filename)
```